# Layered Navigation doesn't show Custom Attribute

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I have created **custom attribute with multiselect option** using code. Its created all the custom attributes, After product Import, multiselect attribute not coming to Shopping options. But viewed in Product Details.

If i created **custom attribute manually its viewed in Shopping Options** but, using code its created , but not viewed in shopping option.

reference:

[image]

This is my code:

```
   $eavSetup->addAttribute(

        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'c_bathrooms',/* Custom Attribute Code */
        [
            'group' => 'Product Details',/* Group name in which you want to display your custom attribute */
            'type' => 'text',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
            'attribute_set' =>  'Attribute Name',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Bathrooms', /* lablel of your attribute*/
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'class' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
            'filterable_in_search' => true,
            'option' => [
                'values' => [
                    '1',
                    '2',
                    '3',
                    '4',
                    '5'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );
```

Suggest me, What i Miss and how to fix this issue

**Note:** if I remove and recreate CustomAttribute, Some custom custom attribute view. not all the multiselect option attribute viewed.

Answer (score 2):

I have given and answer of this question.

Please check this link:

[Adding custom product attributes to layered navigation but not shown](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156391/adding-custom-product-attributes-to-layered-navigation-but-not-shown/157930#157930)